# Connection refused from SprigBoot app to weblogic

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, weblogic

I'm trying to consume a **REST** service from **Postman** by deploying a **war** arctifact in **weblogic** but always have the same error

> "Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8021"

There's no problem with my IP or port.

This is my `application.properties` file

[image]

and this my request

[image]

finally, this is my `Controller` class

```java
package com.app.controller;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.app.model.Employee;
import com.app.repo.EmployeeRepo;

@RestController
public class EmployeeController {

    @Autowired
    private EmployeeRepo repo;

    @PostMapping("/save")
    public ResponseEntity<String> saveEmployee(@RequestBody Employee employee) {
        try {
            repo.save(employee);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return new ResponseEntity<String>("Error al insertar", HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        }
        return new ResponseEntity<String>("Insertado exitosamente", HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

Any help, please?

Comment: `server*` properties don't apply when deploying to a container **only** when using an embedded container. So use the regular port `8080` and the path is the name of your `war` file and not what you have in your `application.properties`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your spring boot application is deployed in weblogic as a war file, then it would be using the weblogic ports, not what you have configured in your application.properties file.

Comment: In that case, what can i do to change the port of my application and not to be forced in using weblogic port?

Comment: Don't build a war file, build a jar (use sprig-boot-maven-plugin repackage goal).  Don't deploy your app to weblogic.  Build a spring boot executable jar with embedded tomcat, which is the default.

Comment: I see, but actually in my work i must use weblogic because actual infrastructure. Saddly using embedded tomcat server is not an option :/.